# DateTime TryParseExact not parsing similar string?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a problem parsing a string representation of a DateTime value back into a DateTime instance using the [DateTime.ParseExact(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

For some reason using similar formatted strings (or maybe I am blind) with different values works for value A) and doesn't another time for value b) and I must be missing something here.. but I just can't find it:

```
var d1 = "14/10/2013 2:16:18 PM";
var d2 = "27/08/2016 12:20:34 PM";

var dFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss tt";

DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue; // out value for .TryParseExact(..)
var tryParseResultD1 = DateTime.TryParseExact(d1, dFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dt);
var tryParseResultD2 = DateTime.TryParseExact(d2, dFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dt);

tryParseResultD1.Dump(); // << returns False
tryParseResultD2.Dump(); // << returns True
```

.. for some reason trying to parse the 'd1' string doesn't work but parsing 'd2' does and I don't know why.

Does anyone know or see what's going on here?

Comment: You should change 'H' for 'h' as 'h' represents _The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12_ and `H` represents _The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23_

Comment: Oh my.. yeah.. I just saw it, too - thanks @MartinParkin !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `H` for `h`.

`h` represents *The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12*.

`H` represents *The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23*.

In your case you want a 12 hour clock from 1 to 12:

```
var dFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the H for h in the format var dFormat?

If I'm correct h stands for 12 hour notation and H for 24 hour.

Comment: Your answer may not be correct; `hh` is _The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12_ so actually he should be using `h`. You can clearly see that he uses a single-digit hour.